# Same session_id() values for different sub domains in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cross-browser, subdomain, sessionid

I have a web page name as page1.php in one sub-domain (Ex. abc.example.com). The content of page1.php as follows.

```
<?php
session_start();

$session_id = session_id();

echo "page4_session_id : ".$session_id."<br />";

?>
```

Then I have another web page name as page2.php in a different sub-domain (Ex. xyz.example.com). The content of page2.php as follows.

```
<?php
session_start();

$page5_session_id = session_id();

echo "page5_session_id : ".$page5_session_id."<br />";

?>
```

When I run the two pages in Google Chrome or Fire Fox browsers, those are giving me different Session ID values for **page4_session_id** and **page5_session_id**. But when I load two web pages in two different tabs in Internet Explorer 10, it gives me same values for  **page4_session_id** and **page5_session_id**.

Why IE behave like that? Is that a feature of IE?

Comment: @Pinoniq It's on IE 10, That I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to specify session cookie domain validity?

```
//for page1.php
session_set_cookie_params(time()+3600, "/", "abc.example.com");

//for page2.php
session_set_cookie_params(time()+3600, "/", "xyz.example.com");
```

from php.net for function session_set_cookie_params

```
Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.

This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get().
```

Comment: what I am not clear is why IE gives different result while other all browsers give expected result.

Comment: from several years of my observations how IE behave, I am hundred percent sure IE is living its own life...

Comment: I put your code but still get the same value for session_id()

Comment: please check with session_get_cookie_params() in both scripts with IE, how domain parameter looks like